# NAIP data for MD,VA, and DE states

Tags: naip

I've been searching around to find NAIP data. The National Agriculture Imagery Program acquires aerial imagery during the agricultural growing seasons in the continental U.S. But I cannot seem to find much online for reliable data I recall there being NAIP data here: https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/  but cannot seem to find it now.

Comment: https://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services

Comment: https://map.dfg.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Comment: https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Comment: @jbalk THANKS SO MUCH! I am doing NDVI analysis for MD,VA,DE crops. From the list of downloads which do you think would be most appropriate for this type of analysis?

Comment: No idea my friend.  I have not done NDVI analysis.  I'm pretty sure they are all .sid files though, so just download all the tiles you need.  The list is tiles of imagery for the state.  There should be a guide telling you what tiles are for what areas.

Comment: @Yen8 I highly recommend using Google Earth Engine (GEE) to both acquire the imagery and perform the analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download from here:  https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip/folder/17936490251

Map Services here:

https://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services

https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Here is a map of the NAIP coverage for each year:

https://www.fsa.usda.gov/Assets/USDA-FSA-Public/usdafiles/APFO/status-maps/pdfs/naipcov_2018.pdf

Comment: Thanks! nrcs.app.box.com I saw before but it unfortunately didn't have the raster data needed for MD, VA, and DE.

Comment: if you're looking for full coverage I think you need to go back to 2016

Comment: Here's the list of names for the naip files (https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip/file/168958604571).  You should be able to get all the rasters you need for your areas but they may be from previous years.

Comment: @Yen8 I added a link to a map of NAIP coverage in my answer

Comment: Thanks! the link for the list of names for the naip files didn't work. Never used JPEG2000 in ArcPro before but it appears that it has the three bands I need to do NDVI analysis. I used the link: https://apps.nationalmap.gov/download    Then I clicked on Imagery - NAIP so downloaded the JPEG2000. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hmmm it appears that I cannot find a place with NAIP of an entire state only very select areas. That's unfortunate.

Comment: There are no statewide downloads.  You will have to download all the tiles (there is complete coverage if you go back to 2016) and merge them into a single raster.  Have you searched for NDVI products?  Maybe there is already some NVDI data available like this https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aa9c87d6f17b452296252bd75005f6a4

Comment: Is there anyway to download that NDVI dataset from arconline?